# Update the price in cart from additional custom discount rate percentage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, discount

I would like to change the product prices. This is what I have tried:

```php
function regular_price_func($price, $product) {     
    if (!empty(get_field("zusatzlicher_rabatt", 'options')['rabatt_status']) && is_product($product->get_id())) {   
        $discount_in_procent = (($product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price()) / $product->get_regular_price()) * 100;
        if ($discount_in_procent > 49) {                    
            return ($product->get_regular_price() - ($product->get_regular_price() / 100) * ($discount_in_procent + get_field("zusatzlicher_rabatt", 'options')['produkte_uber_50']));
        }
        else {
            return ($product->get_regular_price() - ($product->get_regular_price() / 100) * ($discount_in_procent + get_field("zusatzlicher_rabatt", 'options')['produkte_unter_50']));
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'regular_price_func', 10, 2);
```

This will change the price on the product page, but when adding that item to the cart, the cart page still displays the official price, so my function has no effect.

To achieve my goal, I have tried it this way:

```php
function custom_change_product_price($cart_object) {
    foreach ($cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $new_price = 100; 
        $cart_item['data']->set_price($new_price);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_change_product_price');
```

This will change the price to 100. However, I want the price, which I have defined in the function `regular_price_func`. How do I do this?

Comment: Just remove `&& is_product($product->get_id())`from your if statement, to make it work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

`$cart_item['data']` should be an instance of the WC_Product class.

```
function custom_change_product_price($cart_object) {
    foreach ($cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        /*@var \WC_Product $Product*/
        $Product = $cart_item['data'];
        $Product->set_price(
            regular_price_func(
                $Product->get_regular_price(),
                $Product
            )
        ); 
    }
}
```

I seen the other answer that was deleted after I posted this, which is basically the same ( maybe a bit messier ).  I'm not one to steal credit, so when you said "It's not working".  You should make sure your pricing logic works correctly.  There is some conditions in there and some custom options that need to be set.  It's far more likely there is an additional issue there.  If none of those conditions pass then it's just going to return the products original price.  That doesn't mean there is anything wrong with the above code, or the other answer.

```
 I want the price, which I have defined in the function regular_price_func.
```

Your not asking us to validate the logic of that function, which would be impossible, there is stuff ( data ) we just don't have to do that.

I voted to undelete the other answer, that's the most I can do.

One last thing I can add, if you type hint this ( I capitalize objects ):

```
function regular_price_func($price, \WC_Product $Product) {
```

You wont have to check `is_product($Product->get_id())` because it has no choice but to be a product.

Comment: The other answer returned the regular price. Your answer returns the sale price. My code works fine since I see the price on the product page. However, I have removed the entire logic and used `return 15;`. The product page displays the price as 15, however, I am still not able to see 15 in the cart.

Comment: I should have probably used `get_regular_price`.  I didn't see that one tell after I did mine.  I guess it depends what you want the input to be.

Comment: Then I get the regular price, but still not 15.

Comment: I would guess that in the checkout this is not working `get_field("zusatzlicher_rabatt", 'options')['rabatt_status']`

Comment: Oh I see. this is good point!

Comment: Please try this   `function regular_price_func($price, $product) { die(get_field("zusatzlicher_rabatt", 'options')['rabatt_status']); }`  When on the cart page.  I'd have the cart page loaded with a product, then just add `die()` in there and output that value.  It's probably `null` or something like that.  That could make the price function not run.

Comment: I checked on a copy of wordpress I have and the original hook `woocommerce_product_get_price` gets fired on the cart page  you shouldn't need `custom_change_product_price` at all.  It's just likely like I said above that something in the pricing conditions is not available on this page.  I don't know that much about AFC.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that this is the issue. When I use `var_dump(get_field("zusatzlicher_rabatt", 'options')['produkte_unter_50']);`, I get the value in the cart. To be 100 % sure, I have used `var_dump(get_field("zusatzlicher_rabatt", 'options', $product->id)['produkte_unter_50']); `. However, both return the same value.

Comment: I have figured out that the issue was because of `&& is_product($product->get_id())`. When removing it, it worked fine. Silly mistake, but anyway, thanks for your help!